# Remove imported modules from python

Tags: python, module

If I have a python file, named "xtraimport.py" with this in it:

```
import os
import sys

def its_true():
    return True
```

When I import it, it contains the symbol "os" and "sys":

```
In [3]: import xtraimport
In [4]: dir(xtraimport)
Out[4]:
['__builtins__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 'its_true',
 'os',
 'sys']
```

Is there any way to remove the name space pollution? I understand the symbols were imported in my module, but I don't want to expose them to everybody that uses the library.

Comment: It looks like adding `del os` and `del sys` at the end of the module does what I mean. Is there an easier way?

Comment: Why would you want to remove the `os` and `sys` modules, is my question. They're not exactly well-kept secrets, after all.

Comment: This is just an example, I often end up with 10 or more extra modules or functions. If somebody uses auto-complete on the module, they shouldn't have to see all those modules I imported, just the objects/functions I defined as part of the library.

Comment: I don't understand how this is polluting the namespace, though. The only name you have imported into your script is `xtraimport`, and you just use the things you need from there. `os` and `sys` aren't ever directly imported into your main script, so what does it matter if they're available via `xtraimport.sys` etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get some control over this is to make your module into a package.  On the python path, create the `xtraimport`.  In that directory place two files: (1) `xtraimport.py` and (2) `__init__.py`.  For the contents of `__init__.py`, use:

```
from xtraimport import its_true
```

In this way, only `its_true` is directly exposed:

```
In [1]: import xtraimport

In [2]: dir(xtraimport)
Out[2]:
['__builtins__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__path__',
 'its_true',
 'xtraimport']
```

The full contents of `xtraimport` are still available for the dedicated users who are willing to take an extra step:

```
In [3]: dir(xtraimport.xtraimport)
Out[3]:
['__builtins__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 'its_true',
 'os',
 'sys']
```

Answer (score 0):

Easier? Probably not. But here's a solution if you like it.

```
import xtraimport
import sys
originalDir = dir(xtraimport)
newDir      = [x for x in originalDir if x not in sys.modules]
```

Take a look here for more detail on `sys.modules`: [sys.modules](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.modules)

Answer (score 0):

Setting `__all__` allows you to specify which names you would like your module's public interface to contain. It doesn't actually prevent the others from being accessed, but it affects `from foo import *`, pydoc, and it might affect autocomplete depending on the autocomplete software.

E.g.:

`__all__ = ["my_function", "MyClass"]`

Answer (score 0):

To remove an imported module, for example, if I am going to remove the imported cv2 module, I can do so (Python 3.9):

I can see cv2 has been imported with:
`print(dir())`
Now to remove cv2:
`del cv2`
Check it again:
`print(dir())`